# Некорректная работа кнопок, созданных из префаба в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Unity 5.3 игра 2D. На сцене есть два канваса: один для отображения меню, второй для отображения интерфейса сцены. Изначально канвас интерфейса скрыт. При нажатии на кнопку New начинается новая игра, а при нажатии на Load происходит загрузка из сохранения. В обоих случаях канвас меню скрывается, а интерфейс становится активным через `SetActive(true);` Дальше создаются из префаба кнопки в интерфейсе, которые зависят от загруженной локации. Кнопки привязываются к канвасу интерфейса через `btn.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform);`

При запуске игры созданные кнопки появляются в иерархии и привязаны к канвасу, но на сцене их не видно. Если затем выйти в меню и загрузится из сохранения или начать новую игру, то те же кнопки на сцене появляются. С чем может быть связано это мерцание? И как сделать чтобы кнопки отображались сразу?

Comment: Проблему решил изменением иерархии на сцене. Оставил один канвас и кнопки заработали нормально.

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1):

По моей практике, лучшим из решений является использование UI элементов на канвасе.
По возможности канвас скейлер должен быть любым окроме "match width and height". Иначе текст и сами текстуры будут размытыми. **Особенно текст.**
И не использовать устаревший GUI. (это я на всякий случай)

Создай канвас, после чего тупо размещай кнопки как тебе будет удобно. Когда нужно скрыть меню -- просто отключай канвас и все дочерние элементы будут отключатся одним скопом.

Генерить такие кнопки как "старт нью гейм" и "лоад" я бы не советовал. Просто потому, что так их сложно сделать достаточно красивыми и прикручивать к ним анимацию немного сложнее. Это как самый минимум :)

Можно так же отключать панель(дочерний элемент канваса) на которой будут размещены обьекты(в даном случае кнопки). Как альтернативный вариант -- отключать рендерер.

Я делаю много панелей внутри канваса и переключаюсь между ними.